# how to change nav color in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How would I go about modifying the CSS to change the color of the navbar in Bootstrap 4?

How do I fix this?
this my code you can check it

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
      aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #1fd0b6;">Fiverr Pro</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span><img
                src="https://fiverr-dev-res.cloudinary.com/general_assets/flags/1f1fa-1f1f8.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></span><span class="p-2">English</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Become a Seller</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            Join
        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

you can check
this my css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-link {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}


.nav-item {
    margin: 2px;

}
```

is there possible to change color with bootstrap class

Comment: Share your css.

Comment: What you mean by color? text color, background color?

Comment: i mean text color

Comment: @Technicalmirchi your 'a' tags will need the color changing if you want the text color to change - 

  <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #1fd0b6;">Fiverr Pro</a>

Comment: Guys i **change** it i can do change navbar-dark to navbar-light

Comment: @Technicalmirchi remember this, if you have different stylesheet to put your css then don't have inline css, keep everything in CSS and make it clean. Try not to use `!important`, happy coding.

Comment: @Manjuboyz thanks i will keep it and i also upvote bcz you are help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it already has a color set as its class is 'navbar-dark' so you can just change the color directly however usually if a class is already set you will have to change the navbar class to change the color, but you can overwrite this with an !important (not recommended however)

```
.navbar {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

Comment: You should not use `!important` unless it is a last option! I have not downvoted it but I suggest you to change to other answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes as i stated ' (not recommended however)' in my answer, !important should only be used to test, you should directly change the current classes assigned to the navbar - .navbar-dark

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement you want the `navbar` to have color?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #1fd0b6;">Fiverr Pro</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span><img
                src="https://fiverr-dev-res.cloudinary.com/general_assets/flags/1f1fa-1f1f8.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></span><span class="p-2">English</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Become a Seller</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            Join
        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to take a look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Here you can use the navbar-light class instead of the navbar-dark class. Likewise, instead of the bg-transparent class, you can use one of the classes bg-primary, bg-success, bg-info, bg-warning, bg-danger, bg-secondary, bg-dark and bg-ligh for the background color. If you want to use colors other than these, you can define your own classes in a style file that is linked to your page and use the bootstarp classes above. 
for example:

```
.my-bg-color{
   background-color: #123456;
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-brand {
  color: # ff0;
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-brand: hover, .my-navbar-theme .navbar-brand: focus {
  color: # ff0;
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .nav-link: hover, .my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .nav-link: focus {
  color: rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.75);
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .nav-link.disabled {
  color: rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.25);
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .show> .nav-link,
.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .active> .nav-link,
.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.my-navbar-theme .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: # ff0;
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.1);
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url ("data: image / svg + xml,% 3csvg xmlns = 'http: //www.w3.org/2000/svg' width = '30 'height = '30' viewBox = '0 0 30 30 '% 3e% 3cpath stroke =' rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.5) 'stroke-linecap =' round 'stroke-miterlimit = '10' stroke-width = '2' d = 'M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22' / 3c% 3% / 3% SVG ");
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-text {
  color: rgba (255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-text a {
  color: # ff0;
}

.my-navbar-theme .navbar-text a: hover, .my-navbar-theme .navbar-text a: focus {
  color: # ff0;
}
```

You can then add your own classes instead of the bootstrap classes.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg my-navbar-theme my-bg-color">
```